# Can we have multiple dataSources to single database

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jpa, jdbc

I am having spring webservice application with oracle as a database. Right now i have datasource created using weblogic server. Also using eclipse linkg JPA to do both read and write transactions(insert,Read and update). Now we want to separate dataSources for read(read) and wrtie(insert or update) transactions.

My current dataSource is as followed:

```
JNDI NAME : jdbc/POI_DS
URL : jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE
```

using this, I am doing both read and write transactions.

What if i do the following:

```
JNDI NAME : jdbc/POI_DS_READ
URL : jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE

JNDI NAME : jdbc/POI_DS_WRITE
URL : jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE
```

I knew that using XA datasource we can define multiple dataSources. Can I do same thing without XA dataSource. Does any one tried this kind of approach.

**::UPDATE::**

Thank you all for your responses I have implemented following solution.

I have taken the multiple database approach. where you will define multiple `transactionManagers` and `managerFactory`. I have taken only single non xa dataSource(JNDI) that is refereed in `EntityManagerFactory` Bean.

you can reefer following links here which are for multiple dataSources
[Multiple DataSource Approach](http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/how-to-setup-multiple-data-sources-with-spring-and-jpa/)
[defining @transactional value](http://gik.firetrot.com/index.php/2013/12/06/spring-with-multiple-transaction-managers/)

Also explored on transaction managers `org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebLogicJtaTransactionManager` and `org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager` as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is an interesting article about this in Spring docs - [Dynamic DataSource Routing](http://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/). There is an example there, that allows you to basically switch data sources at runtime. It should help you. I'd gladly help you more, if you have any more specific questions.

EDIT: It tells, that the actual use is to have connection to multiple databases via one configuration, but you could manage to create different configs to one database with different params, as you'd need to.

Comment: quick Question, URL property defined differenly for  gold,silver and bronze. jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:${db.port.gold}/blog. In my case if use same thing does it have any issue. Also i am using EclipseLink as my JPA. Let me execute this approch first.

Comment: Just create an Enum with READ and WRITE properties, it could work the same way. Provide required properties, as you need. I don't think there would be some additional issues about the JPA provider.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Database "services". Each workload, read-only and read-write, would be using its own service to access the database. That way you can use AWR reports to get statistics for each service. You can also turn off read-write when you keep read-only up and running.

Here is a pointer to the Oracle Database documentation that talks about Services:
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/create.htm#CIABBCAI

Answer (score 0):

If you're using spring, you should be able to accomplish this without using 2 Datasources via spring `@Transactional` with the `readonly` property set to true. The reason why I suggest this is that you seem to be concerned about the transactionality only and this seems to be catered for in the spring framework?

I'd suggest something like this for your case:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class DefaultFooService implements FooService {

    public Foo getFoo(String fooName) {
        // do something
    }

    // these settings have precedence for this method
    @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void updateFoo(Foo foo) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Using this style, you should be able to split read only services from their write counterparts, or even have read and write service methods combined. But both of these do not use 2 datasources.

Code is from the [Spring Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html)

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that you need to address the problem on the database / connection url + properties layer. 
I would google around for something like read write replication.

Related to your question with JPA and transaction. You are doomed when you are using multiple Datasources. Also XA datasources are not really a solution for that. The only thing they do for you is to ensure consistency over multi data source operations. XA Transaction do only span some sort of logical transaction over two transactions (one for each datasource). From the transaction isolation point of view (as long as your not using READ_UNCOMMITED) both datasources use their own transaction. This means the read data source would not see the changes made by the write transaction.